# Finding Kernel, Range and Dimensions of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the kernel and range, and state their dimensions, of the following linear transformation $L : R^3 \rightarrow R^3, L(x)= (x_1,x_1,x_1). $

**Def:** Let $L: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation the kernel of L denoted ker(L) is defined by $\text{ker}(L)= \{v \in V | L(v) = 0 \;_W \}
$

**Def:** Let $L:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation and let S be a subspace of V. The image of $S$, denoted $L(S)$ is defined by $L(S)= \{ w \in W| w= L(v) \text{ for some} v \in S\}$

The image of the entire space $L(v)$ is called the range of $L$.

How does one use these theories in order to solve this question? Any hints at an approach would be welcomed.

Comment: Looking at where $L$ sends the basis vectors $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ is a good start. Hopefully once you have done that, you will have a rough idea about what the kernel and range of $L$ might be.

Comment: @michaelhowes How do you know that those are the basis vectors?

Comment: they are one possible set of a basis vectors. They are basis vectors because for all $v \in R^3$, we can find unique $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in R$ such that $v=c_1(1,0,0)+c_2(0,1,0)+c_3(1,0,0)$.

Comment: If I have another example like this will the basis remain the same? Will this always be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $L:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ mapping $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto (x_1,x_1,x_1)$.

Its kernel, by definition, consists of those real triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which are mapped to $(0,0,0)$ by $L$. For this specific $L$ above, these are exactly the ones where $x_1=0$ and $x_2,x_3$ are arbitrary. 
These can be parametrized without further restrictions with $2$ real numbers (namely, by $x_2$ and $x_3$), so it will be a $2$ dimensional space. 
Turning this into the language of bases, just get the vectors where one of the parameters is $1$, and the rest are $0$. 
In our case, $(0,1,0)$, $\ (0,0,1)$ will give a basis for $\ker L$.

Its range, by definition, consists of the possible values the function can take. These are now $(a,a,a)$ for all possible real $a$. $\ $ [Indeed, e.g. $L(a,0,0)=(a,a,a)$ for any $a\in\Bbb R$.] 
It can be given with $1$ parameter, it will have dimension $1$, and a basis is given by $(1,1,1)$.